# Exact area of $x<\sqrt{(x-\frac{1}{4})^2+y^2}-2(x-\frac{1}{4})^2-2y^2+\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: integration, area

$x<\sqrt{(x-\frac{1}{4})^2+y^2}-2(x-\frac{1}{4})^2-2y^2+\frac{1}{4}$
I was able to get to the integral part (I'll see if you can get there yourself, if not I'll share how) but I cannot seem to solve the integrals (I was doing it without double integrals)
This may help: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ivqvqdprkv
Someone found a solution using double integrals so if you want to solve it without double integrals, try: [Exact area of $x<\sqrt{(x-\frac{1}{4})^2+y^2}-2(x-\frac{1}{4})^2-2y^2+\frac{1}{4}$ without using double integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772197/exact-area-of-x-sqrtx-frac142y2-2x-frac142-2y2-frac14)

Comment: Maybe you can try like this: let $s=x-\frac{1}{4}, t=y^2\geq 0$, then the problem is transformed into the following:$$s<\sqrt{s^2+t}-2s^2-2t$$

Comment: Move the origin to $(\frac14,0)$ and switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: @ItozDarbien i did that except s=$(x-\frac{1}{4})^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the curve defined by $$ x = \sqrt{\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+y^2} - 2\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 -2y^2 + \frac{1}{4}$$
can be expressed as the image of $\alpha: [0,2\pi] \to \Bbb{R}^2$, where $$\alpha(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos{t}\right)(\cos{t},\sin{t}) + \left(\frac{1}{4},0\right)$$
Since the translation has no influence over the area, we can simply consider another curve $\beta: [0,2\pi] \to \Bbb{R}^2 $ defined by $$\beta(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos{t}\right)(\cos{t},\sin{t})$$
To simplify calculations, let's define $\rho(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos{t}\right)$.

We shall use Green's Theorem to calculate the desired area. Consider the vector field $$H(x,y) = (H_1(x,y),H_2(x,y)) = \frac{1}{2}(-y,x)$$ and let $D$ be the region bounded by $\beta$ . Therefore, by Green's Theorem, we know that $$\oint_{\beta}H \,dS = \iint_{D} \left(\frac{\partial H_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial H_1}{\partial y}\right) \, dxdy = \iint_D \,dxdy$$
and this last double integral gives us the area of D. All we need to do is compute the left-most integral.

$$\beta'(t)=\rho'(\cos t, \sin t)+\rho(-\sin t,\cos t)$$
And so we have $$\oint_{\beta}H \,dS = \int_0^{2\pi} \lt H(\beta(t)),\beta'(t) \gt \,dt$$
which equals
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \lt \frac{1}{2}(-\rho(t)\sin t,\rho(t) \cos t), (\rho'(t)\cos t - \rho(t) \sin t, \rho'(t) \sin t + \rho(t)\cos t) \gt \,dt = \\[12pt] = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}\rho(t)^2 \, dt$$
And this last integral is easy to calculate: $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos t)\right)^2 \, dt = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos ^2 t}{8} - \frac{\cos t}{4} + \frac{1}{8} \, dt = \frac{3\pi}{8}$$
which is the value of the desired area.

Comment: I did it my own way and got the same number