# Exact area of $x<\sqrt{(x-\frac{1}{4})^2+y^2}-2(x-\frac{1}{4})^2-2y^2+\frac{1}{4}$ without using double integrals

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, area

In [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771452/exact-area-of-x-sqrtx-frac142y2-2x-frac142-2y2-frac14) I asked for the exact area of $x<\sqrt{(x-\frac{1}{4})^2+y^2}-2(x-\frac{1}{4})^2-2y^2+\frac{1}{4}$
someone found a way to do it with double integrals, now I'm asking for proof without using double integrals
This may help: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ivqvqdprkv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the polar coordinate system

$$\begin{cases}x - \frac{1}{4} = r\cos\theta \\ y = r\sin\theta\end{cases}$$

which simplifies the expression of the area of the curve to

$$r\cos\theta < r - 2r^2 \implies r < \frac{1-\cos\theta}{2} $$

since $r$ is understood to be nonnegative. This is a cardioid or limacon, which reaches the origin only at integer multiples of $2\pi$. The formula for polar area is given by

$$A = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} r^2(\theta)\:d\theta = \frac{1}{8}\int_0^{2\pi} 1 - 2\cos\theta + \cos^2\theta\:d\theta$$

$$ = \frac{1}{8}(2\pi - 0 + \pi) = \boxed{\frac{3\pi}{8}}$$

as desired.